# @RefreshScope together with @Order

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I'm trying to use `@RefreshScope` with `@Order`. Bootrun fails with error

```
@Order on WebSecurityConfigurers must be unique. Order of 2147483636 was already used on com.company.rest.config.ActuatorSecurityConf$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1e7c9a55@6559faf1, so it cannot be used on com.company.rest.config.ActuatorSecurityConf$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1e7c9a55@6559faf1 too.
```

`@RefreshScope` makes the bean getting initialized more than once because it uses proxy. Is it possible to use `@RefreshScope` with `@Order`?

```
@Configuration
@Order(ManagementServerProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
@RefreshScope
public class ActuatorSecurityConf extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private ApplicationProperties properties;

    public ActuatorSecurityConf(ApplicationProperties properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser(properties.getActuatorUsername())
            .password(properties.getActuatorUserPassword())
            .roles("ACTUATOR");
        // @formatter:on
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http.antMatcher("/manage/**")
                .csrf().disable()
                .cors()
            .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/manage/info").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().hasRole("ACTUATOR")
            .and()
                .httpBasic();
        // @formatter:on
    }

}
```

Update:

Removed `@RefreshScope` from `@Configuration` as suggested but the error still occurs.

`@Order(ManagementServerProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)` is required to place it before another `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` in the app with 
`@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)`.

```
@Order(ManagementServerProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class ActuatorSecurityConf extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private ApplicationProperties properties;

    @Autowired
    public ActuatorSecurityConf(ApplicationProperties properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // same
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // same
    }
}

@Configuration
class ApplicationConfig {
    @Bean
    @RefreshScope
    public ApplicationProperties applicationProperties() {
        return new ApplicationProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @RefreshScope
    public ActuatorSecurityConf actuatorSecurityConf() {
        return new ActuatorSecurityConf(applicationProperties());
    }
}
```

Using Spring boot 1.5.4.RELEASE

Comment: The error says you have to change the value of `@Order`, nothing to do with `@RefreshScope`? It's not generally a good idea to use `@RefreshScope` on `@Configuration` classes.

Comment: @spencergibb  `@Order ` was used to place it before another `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` in the app. Updated my question...tried without `@RefreshScope` on `@Configuration`, but error still occurs.

Comment: Then it's not a refresh scope issue